# How to add functions to .bash_profile?

Tags: bash

This is a very noob question but I'm finding it difficult to nail it down quickly.

I want to write a bash script that lets me start and shut down tomcat as I require, regardless of my current working director.

I know how to write functions in bash, I want to know how to execute a .sh.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Add the tomcat bin directory to your PATH

Comment: but i would still like to know how to run from bash

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. A shell function is invoked by name, the same as any other command.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `alias`. Put this in your bashrc or profile for example:

```
alias lsft="find ./ -type f | grep -E '.*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$' | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n"
```

So if you logout/login or run `source .bash-profile` you can run lsft and it will list all the files by type in the current directory

Comment: How is defining an alias any different from defining a function? (Aside from losing the ability to pass arguments and use it by default in a non-interactive shell?)

Comment: I've never heard of running functions as a command, but that might be my basic shell knowledge. Anyway, you can just pass arguments to an aliassed command.

Comment: Aliases cannot receive arguments; you can only follow the expansion of an alias with arguments. Either a shell function or an executable may be used as a simple command.